# Converting Query Expression into Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having trouble converting a Query Expression found here: http://www.oak3.org/crm/workflow-activity-checking-duplicate-instances/
into a linq query. To put it simply, the goal is if two workflows get triggered at the same time, only let one go through sorted by most recent. Currently my linq version will sometimes cancel a workflow even if it is the only one running. I know I need to utilize the input parameter somehow (to tell it what workflow to compare to), and I'm sure there could be more issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
        [Input("Current workflow")]
        [ReferenceTarget("workflow")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> workflowReferenceInput { get; set; } 
        [Output("Is first workflow")]
    public OutArgument<Boolean> isFirstWorkflow { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        ITracingService tracer = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
        IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        try
        {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            isFirstWorkflow.Set(executionContext, false);

            var wfReference = workflowReferenceInput.Get(executionContext);
            var wfEntity = service.Retrieve("workflow", wfReference.Id, new ColumnSet ( "name" ));

            ConditionExpression ce1 = new ConditionExpression();
            ce1.AttributeName = "statuscode";
            ce1.Operator = ConditionOperator.In;
            ce1.Values.Add(0);
            ce1.Values.Add(10);
            ce1.Values.Add(20);
            ce1.Values.Add(21);
            ce1.Values.Add(22);
            FilterExpression fe1 = new FilterExpression();
            fe1.Conditions.Add(ce1);

            QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
            qe.EntityName = AsyncOperation.EntityLogicalName;
            qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet();
            qe.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
            qe.Criteria.AddFilter(fe1);
            var childFilter = qe.Criteria.AddFilter(LogicalOperator.And);
            childFilter.AddCondition("operationtype", ConditionOperator.Equal, 10);
            childFilter.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, wfEntity["name"]);

            LinkEntity link = new LinkEntity
            {
                LinkFromEntityName = AsyncOperation.EntityLogicalName,
                LinkToEntityName = Quote.EntityLogicalName,
                LinkFromAttributeName = "regardingobjectid",
                LinkToAttributeName = "quoteid"
            };
            link.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("quoteid", ConditionOperator.Equal, context.PrimaryEntityId.ToString());

            DataCollection<Entity> result = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe).Entities;

            var list = result.ToList().OrderBy(c => c.Id);
            for (var i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
            {
                var item = list.ElementAt(i);
                if(item.Id == context.OperationId && i == 0)
                {
                    isFirstWorkflow.Set(executionContext, true);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

into this:

```
 public class WorkflowChecker: CodeActivity
{
    [Input("Current workflow")]
    [ReferenceTarget("workflow")]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> workflowReferenceInput { get; set; }

    [Output("Is first workflow")] public OutArgument<Boolean> isFirstWorkflow { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();

        try
        {                
            var ok = WorkflowChecker(context.PrimaryEntityId, context.OperationId);

            isFirstWorkflow.Set(executionContext, ok);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

which calls:

```
 public static bool WorkflowChecker(Guid workflowContextId,
        Guid asyncOperationId)
    {
        var someReturnValue = false;
        var listOfWorkflowIds = new List<Guid>();

        try
        {
            var query = from async in AsyncOperationSet
                join b in BSet on async.RegardingObjectId.Id equals b.Id                        
                where b.Id.Equals(workflowContextId)
                      && (async.StateCode.Equals(0)
                          || async.StateCode.Equals(1)
                          || async.StateCode.Equals(2))
                select new {async.AsyncOperationId};
            foreach (var x in query)
            {
                if (x.AsyncOperationId != Guid.Empty)
                {
                    listOfWorkflowIds.Add(x.AsyncOperationId.Value);
                }
            }

            listOfWorkflowIds.Sort();

            if (listOfWorkflowIds.First() == asyncOperationId)
            {
                someReturnValue = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in Workflow Checker: " + e);
        }


        return someReturnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the following lines to the workflow library then passed the parameter into the call to compare by name and so far it appears to be working successfully:

```
var wfReference = workflowReferenceInput.Get(executionContext);
var wfEntity = service.Retrieve("workflow", wfReference.Id, new ColumnSet("name"));
var test =  wfEntity["name"];
```